# Are there any stats available on the usage of libraries by deep learning researchers?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, reference-request, keras, pytorch

I know three Python libraries that are popular in deep learning research community: [Keras](https://keras.io/), [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/), [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/).  I don't know much about [Theano](https://github.com/Theano/Theano).

This question is not about the efficiency, flexibility or ease of the library for its users. This question is about the usage of the library by the deep learning (academic, research) community.

Which library is used by most of the contemporary researchers? Is there any comparison or stats available among the libraries, based on GitHub implementations or by some other means?

Comment: https://pypistats.org/about

Answer (score 1):

Something that I personally use is [Google Trends](https://trends.google.com/trends/). This is a very useful tool for verifying the interest of a broad public on some subject. Results can even be refined to  include region and/or time span.

For instance, here you can see a comparison for the interest in Tensorflow, Keras and Pytorch over the past 12 months:

[image]